# Visual studio  How to set the active test settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file, testing, settings, solution

Hi
My question is about how can i set the active test settings in the project file for visual studio 2010, I mean, what flag or entry does the visual studio modify in the solution file or where is that setting.
Im developing a solution file generator but cant find the way to auto select the required test settings as the default settings

Answer (score 6):

If you do not see anything under the Menu Item "Test > Select Active Test Settings" or "Test > Edit Test Settings", Check your Solution Explorer window for files ending with ".testsettings" under the "Solution Items" folder.

If there are not any .testsettings files, you can right click the "Solution Items" or "Solution" folder, then click on "Add" then select "New Item". Under the "Installed Templates" select "Test Settings". Select the "Test Settings" template, name the file, and click the "Add" button. This is now part of your solution and now appears in the "Test > Select Active Test Settings" and "Test > Edit Test Settings" menu items.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, the active test settings is stored in the .vsmdi file, not the solution file.

Edit: specifically, it is the "storage" attribute on the RunConfiguration element in the .vsmdi file.